# How do I define an object in the header file? (without using it)

Tags: c++

Sorry if the question title isn't confusing but I'm not sure how to word it better.

Basically, here is my code.

**Header File**

```
class Foo {
     public: 
          Foo();
     private: 
          Bar * b;
}

class Bar {
     public:
          Bar(Foo *f);
     private:
          Foo * foo;
}
```

**cpp File**

```
Foo::Foo() {
     new Bar(this);
}

Bar::Bar(Foo * f) {
     foo = f;
}
```

I am trying to pass the values to each other back and forth but Bar is not declared to Foo. How do I make Bar known to Foo?

Comment: Side note: solvable (as answered by @i_am_jorf below), but possibly indicating a flaw in the design (not sure what you're trying to achieve since it is not given in the context of the question).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
class Bar;  // <-- Forward declaration.

class Foo {
     public: 
          Foo();
     private: 
          Bar * b;
}
```

Comment: You're welcome.  The forward declaration is a common idiom for avoiding these sorts of chicken-and-egg problems.